# JTabbedPane gives null pointer exception

Tags: java, arrays, swing, oop

I'm using JTabbedPane with different panels and i'm using gridLayout for the buttons array that i will add. I tried looping the buttons to much more easy code. But i got a null pointer exception i don't how did i get that kind of error.
here's my code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import java.awt.*;
public class HotelRoomsGUI extends JPanel{
    private JTabbedPane mainJTP;
    private JPanel classicTab,deluxeTab,presidentialTab,classicSubPanel,deluxeSubPanel,presidentialSubPanel;
    private String classicRoomNo[] = {"101","102","103","104","105","106","107","108","109","101","111","112"};
    private String deluxeRoomNo[] = {"201","202","203","204","205","206","207","208","209","201","211","212"};
    private String presidentialRoomNo[] = {"301","302","303","304","305","306","307","308","309","301","311","312"};
    private JButton[] classicRoom, deluxeRoom, presidentialRoom;
    public HotelRoomsGUI(){

        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(new Color(90,90,90));
        add(tabbedPane());

    }
    public JPanel classic()
    {
        classicTab = new JPanel();
        classicTab.setBackground(new Color(70,70,70));
        classicTab.setLayout(null);
        classicSubPanel();
        return classicTab;
    }
    public JPanel classicSubPanel()
    {
        classicSubPanel = new JPanel();
        classicSubPanel.setBounds(10,10,605,455);
        classicSubPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3,10,10));
        classicSubPanel.setBackground(new Color(70,70,70));
        classicTab.add(classicSubPanel);
        rooms();
        return classicTab;
    }
    public JPanel deluxe()
    {
        deluxeTab = new JPanel();
        deluxeTab.setBackground(new Color(70,70,70));
        deluxeTab.setLayout(null);
        deluxeSubPanel();
        return deluxeTab;
    }
    public JPanel deluxeSubPanel()
    {
        deluxeSubPanel = new JPanel();
        deluxeSubPanel.setBounds(10,10,605,455);
        deluxeSubPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3,10,10));
        deluxeSubPanel.setBackground(new Color(70,70,70));
        deluxeTab.add(deluxeSubPanel);
        rooms();
        return deluxeSubPanel;
    }
    public JPanel presidential()
    {
        presidentialTab = new JPanel();
        presidentialTab.setBackground(new Color(70,70,70));
        presidentialTab.setLayout(null);
        presidentialSubPanel();
        return presidentialTab;
    }
    public JPanel presidentialSubPanel()
    {
        presidentialSubPanel = new JPanel();
        presidentialSubPanel.setBounds(10,10,605,455);
        presidentialSubPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3,10,10));
        presidentialSubPanel.setBackground(new Color(70,70,70));
        presidentialTab.add(presidentialSubPanel);
        rooms();
        return presidentialSubPanel;
    }
    public JTabbedPane tabbedPane()
    {
        UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected", Color.ORANGE); 
        mainJTP = new JTabbedPane();
        mainJTP.setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
        mainJTP.setBounds(3,1,630,500);
        mainJTP.addTab("Classic",classic());
        mainJTP.addTab("Deluxe",deluxe());
        mainJTP.addTab("Presidential",presidential());
        return mainJTP;
    }
    public void rooms()
    {
        JButton presidentialRoom[] = new JButton[presidentialRoomNo.length];        
        JButton deluxeRoom[] = new JButton[deluxeRoomNo.length];
        JButton classicRoom[] = new JButton[classicRoomNo.length];
        for(int x = 0;x<classicRoomNo.length;x++){
            //classic rooms
            ImageIcon imageC = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\John\\workspace\\SystemTest\\src\\Images\\classicRooms.JPG"); // image
            classicRoom[x] = new JButton(classicRoomNo[x],imageC);
            classicRoom[x].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            classicRoom[x].setBorder(new CompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.WHITE,Color.GRAY),
                    BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.WHITE,Color.GRAY)));
            classicSubPanel.add(classicRoom[x]);
            //deluxe rooms
            ImageIcon imageD = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\John\\workspace\\SystemTest\\src\\Images\\deluxeRooms.JPG"); // image
            deluxeRoom[x] = new JButton(deluxeRoomNo[x],imageD);
            deluxeRoom[x].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            deluxeRoom[x].setBorder(new CompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.WHITE,Color.GRAY),
                    BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.WHITE,Color.GRAY)));
            deluxeSubPanel.add(deluxeRoom[x]);
            //presidential rooms
            ImageIcon imageP = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\John\\workspace\\SystemTest\\src\\Images\\presidentialRooms.JPG"); // image
            presidentialRoom[x] = new JButton(deluxeRoomNo[x],imageP);
            presidentialRoom[x].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            presidentialRoom[x].setBorder(new CompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.WHITE,Color.GRAY),
                    BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.WHITE,Color.GRAY)));
            presidentialSubPanel.add(presidentialRoom[x]);

        }
    }
}
```

and please give me some tips on how i can code more clearer and much better approach

Comment: Don't use null layout; add the stack trace & show the line number; edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at my suggestion, this is your `tabbedPane()` method:

```
public JTabbedPane tabbedPane() {
    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected", Color.ORANGE);
    mainJTP = new JTabbedPane();
    mainJTP.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    mainJTP.setBounds(3, 1, 630, 500);
    mainJTP.addTab("Classic", classic());
    mainJTP.addTab("Deluxe", deluxe());
    mainJTP.addTab("Presidential", presidential());
    rooms();  // I've inserted this, no panic!
    return mainJTP;
}
```

In the method above, the calls to `classic(), deluxe()` and `presidential()` already triggers invocations on `rooms()` method if you trace carefully. Instead, make one `rooms()` call as I've just done above. Remove calls to `rooms()` from elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Can you explain more about my error.. I'm interested on your approach.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a `NullPointerException` as `deluxeSubPanel` has not been instantiated when calling `rooms()` when calling:

```
deluxeSubPanel.add(deluxeRoom[x]);
```

As a general guideline, better to use a top-down approach when creating components with dependent components. This would make the creation order —`JTabbedPane`-`JPanel`-Sub-Components.

Comment: Can you give an example of top down approach? make a code just for demonstration. Thanks